# Rails開発中にRubyプロセスが残り続ける

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsの開発中にターミナルから以下のコマンドでコンソールを起動しています。

`bundle exec spring rails console`

上記コマンドを`quit`で終了してもアクティビティモニタに`ruby`プロセスが残り続けます。原因がわかるかた教えてください。

- macOS 10.12.3
- Rails 5.0.2
- Ruby 2.4.0 : rbenvでインストール
- Puma 3.7.1
- Spring 2.0.1

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`quit` 後、 `bundle exec spring status` を実行すると分かると思います。

```
$ bundle exec spring status
Spring is running:

13064 spring server | myapp | started 6 secs ago
13065 spring app    | myapp | started 7 secs ago | development mode
```

次回の起動を速くするために、重たいフレームワークの読み込み処理を済ませたプロセスが待機しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます！スッキリしました。